# No Rule to Make Target - New in Android NDK

Tags: android-ndk, ndk-build

I am making an attempt to write an NDK basic app to understand how NDK works. I have a text view and a button in the MainActivity and a library class HelloWorldLib.java which have the static native function helloWorld. I have created the header file copied it and created the ".c" file in the jni folder.

When i am building via ndk-build i am getting the error "no rule to make target" error. I checked lots of posts and answer but nothing worked.

I included a test.c empty file  as indicated in the below link and was able to build the project,However, when i ran my app i got the error that " no native implementation found" which is bizzare because i have the implementation.
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66937

```
OnClick from where HelloWorldLib is called.
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String inNDK = HelloWorldLib.helloWorld();
    tv.setText(inNDK);

}

HelloWorldLib where native is funciton is defined.
public class HelloWorldLib {

    public native static String helloWorld();

    static{
        System.loadLibrary("com.example.androidndk_HelloWorldLib");
    }
}

header file created by Javah -jni
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class com_example_androidndk_HelloWorldLib */

#ifndef _Included_com_example_androidndk_HelloWorldLib
#define _Included_com_example_androidndk_HelloWorldLib
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     com_example_androidndk_HelloWorldLib
 * Method:    helloWorld
 * Signature: ()Ljava/lang/String;
 */
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_androidndk_HelloWorldLib_helloWorld
  (JNIEnv *, jclass);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif

C file copied from .h and then modified.
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <com_example_androidndk_HelloWorldLib.h>
#include <string.h>

extern "C" {

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_androidndk_HelloWorldLib_helloWorld
    (JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz){


    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello from JNI !  Compiled with ABI");
}

Andoid.mk file
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := com.example.androidndk_HelloWorldLib.c
LOCAL_MODULE := com.example.androidndk_HelloWorldLib
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

The error i am getting in the command prompt is shown below:

D:\Users\gabhatia\Desktop\Android SDK\MyWorkspace\AndroidNDK>ndk-build
make.exe: *** No rule to make target `jni/com.example.androidndk_HelloWorldLib.c
', needed by `obj/local/x86/objs/com.example.androidndk_HelloWorldLib/com.exampl
 e.androidndk_HelloWorldLib.o'.  Stop.
```

I am not sure where i am getting wrong but any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.
GB.

Comment: Sorry this went under the radar for more than a year. I hope your problem has long been resolved. From your post it isn't clear where the `com.example.androidndk_HelloWorldLib.c` file lives on the file system, but **ndk-build** looks for it right next to **Android.mk**.

Answer (score 0):

Here

`LOCAL_SRC_FILES := com.example.androidndk_HelloWorldLib.c`

`LOCAL_MODULE := com.example.androidndk_HelloWorldLib`

**change to**

`FILE_LIST := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/*.cpp)`

`LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(FILE_LIST:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)`

Have a try.